# Mostrar imagem e upload de um input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, upload, imagem

Olá, gostaria de saber como pegar o caminho de uma imagem contida no value de um input do tipo  file. Estou a usar o seguinte código:

```
$(document).on("change",'#Upload',function(){
         var valor=$(this).attr('value');
         var ext= (valor.substring(valor.lastIndexOf("."))).toLowerCase();
     if (ext==".jpg" || ext==".jpeg"){         
         $("#Image").attr("src", valor);
     }else{alert('Extensao "'+ext+'" nao permitida!');}
});
```

Ele retorna um fakepath, ou seja, um caminho falso. alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Trocar `var valor=$(this).attr('value');` por `var valor=$(this).val();` não resolve o problema?

Comment: Ele retorna igualmente o seguinte valor:
C:/fakepath/imagem_teste.jpg

Comment: Creio que os navegadores não permitam que você tenha acesso ao diretório original, devido a questões de segurança do usuário.

Comment: Alguma maneira de fazer uma espécie de visualização da imagem a ser carregada na própria página?

Comment: É uma página localhost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não funciona dessa forma. O que você tem acesso é o conteúdo do arquivo, e não o caminho dele.

Para mostrar uma imagem que corresponde ao arquivo faça assim:

```
$(document).on("change", "#Upload", function(e) {
    showThumbnail(this.files);
});

function showThumbnail(files) {
    if (files && files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#thumbnail').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    }
}
```

### [Exemplo funcionando no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SrC6v/1/)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Grato pela ajuda!

Comment: É possível marcar uma resposta como aceita. Saiba mais: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)

Answer (score 0):

O "fakepath" é uma medida de segurança que alguns browsers implementam para evitar que o javascript saiba o caminho dos arquivos.

Não acredito que exista uma forma de obter o caminho sem recorrer a algum tipo de componente externo (flash?), ou sem desabilitar alguma configuração de segurança do browser.