# Como selecionar uma foto e carregar na div?

Tags: javascript

```
<!--Container para colocar a imagem de perfil-->
              <div id="imagem">
              </div>
              <!--Botão para selecionar a foto-->
              <input id="teste" class="botao_foto_perfil" type="file" name="flefoto"/>

<script>
    $('#teste').val();

    var img = $('#teste').val();
    $('#id_sua_img').attr('src', img);
</script>
```

Comment: não funcionou, continua não aparecendo

Comment: Você tem que importar o *jQuery*: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` e fazer como está [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/12095/60376).

Comment: Não funcionou do mesmo jeito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar o [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

```js
$("#teste").change(function(){
   if($(this).val()){ // só se o input não estiver vazio
      var img = this.files[0]; // seleciona o arquivo do input
      var f = new FileReader(); // cria o objeto FileReader
      f.onload = function(e){ // ao carregar a imagem
         $("#id_sua_img").attr("src",e.target.result); // altera o src da imagem
      }
      f.readAsDataURL(img); // lê o arquivo
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imagem">
    <img id="id_sua_img" src="" />
</div>
<!--Botão para selecionar a foto-->
<input id="teste" class="botao_foto_perfil" type="file" name="flefoto"/>
```

Comment: agora sim, meu codigo esta com um bug que só esta reconhecendo javaScript no final do codigo por isso não estava funcionando, muito obrigada me ajudou muito

Comment: eu não sei como fazer isso

Comment: ok muito obrigada