# Caminho absoluto de arquivo com Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arquivo

Estou fazendo um bloco de notas com JavaScript e Electron, e tenho um problema: pegar o **caminho absoluto** do arquivo carregado pelo meu `input[type=file]`.

Preciso disso pois quero **salvar** os arquivos **sem precisar abrir** nenhuma janela do explorador de arquivos.

Já tentei pegar o caminho pelo próprio input a partir da propriedade `.value`, mas me retorna assim: `C:\fakepath\arquivo.txt`
Se tiver alguma forma de fazer isso via **Node.js** ou um **keyframe** eu vou tentar fazer.

Meu código para salvar:

```js
document.querySelector('button[data-save]').onclick = () => {
    const data = document.querySelector('textarea.input-main').value

    fs.writeFile(openFile.value, data, err => {
        console.log(err || 'Arquivo Salvo!')
    })
}
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12088/mostrar-imagem-e-upload-de-um-input

Comment: Valeu Novic, o link me foi útil.